# lowp vs. mediump vs. highp in glsl?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, shader

I've been working for the past week on a custom shader. I had various strange issues that were not resolved until I switched almost all floating-point variables to `highp`.

However, today I discovered that a bicubic interpolation algorithm would actually have color banding if I used `highp` for the input texture coordinates (which are between 0 and 1.0). If I use `mediump` it works fine.

I was wondering if someone could explain why this is. According to this document:

http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf

`highp` has a floating point magnitude range of 2^-62 to 2^62, and a floating point precision (relative) of 2^-16.

Whereas `mediump` has a floating point magnitude range of 2^-14 to 2^14, and floating point precision (relative) of 2^-10.

If I'm understanding this correctly, this *should* mean that `mediump` would always be less accurate than `highp`. Why is this not the case?

Comment: Maybe because there's a bug in your shader. Or because you're testing the wrong things in your shader. Or any number of reasons that we can't deduce because you *didn't* post your actual shader.